# How to import python module from within the project in blender?

Tags: scripting, blend-files

## The problem:

I've created two scripts in blender (`importTest` and `loggingConfig`), as shown in the following picture:

[image: Modules example]

But when I try to import `loggingConfig` I obtain the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'loggingConfig'
```

## Options tried:

### importTest (Try #1):

```
import loggingConfig
```

### importTest (Try #2):

```
import bpy
import sys

dir = bpy.data.filepath
print(dir)
if not dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(dir)

import loggingConfig
```

In both cases obtaining the error above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For blender below 2.8

The script to be imported must have the '.py' suffix (e.g. `loggingConfig.py`), it can be imported as follows:

```
import loggingConfig
```

If loggingConfig suffered any changes, you must reloaded, like this:

```
import loggingConfig

# The following lines reload the module in each run
import imp
imp.reload(loggingConfig)
```

This can be ran each time to ensure to have always the most up to date version of `loggingConfig.py`.

## For blender >= 2.8

The script to be imported does not need to have the '.py' suffix (e.g. `loggingConfig`), it can be imported the following:

```
import bpy

loggingConfig = bpy.data.texts["loggingConfig"].as_module()
```

In this case it isn't necessary to reload the script in each run.