# Does Blender text editor not support custom module importing?

Tags: python, scripting, export, import, text-editor

In VSC, this code works

```
import bpy
from subp.panel import Panel

Panel.test()
```

However, in the Blender text editor, Suddenly it doesn't work

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subp'

If I change the second line to `from .subp.panel import Panel` then

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Why can't I run the code in the blender text editor like this?

When I move the `panel.py` to the outside of the `subp` folder and change to `from .panel import Panel`, it throws the same error

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Try removing the first "." from the `from .subp.panel import Panel` and see if that works.

Comment: @Jakemoyo It doesn't work neither. Terminal throws the error`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subp'`.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the root of your custom module?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181036/86891 ?

Comment: @Jakemoyo I think it is, yes. My directory looks like this `Overlay - __init__.py, panel.py` right now.

Comment: @Gorgious I'm using version 2.93.1 but the way you linked, it throws this error; `KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "panel" not found'`.

Comment: @Gorgious I changed `from ... import` line to this; `Panel = bpy.data.texts["panel"].as_module()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Hopefully clearer answer in response to comments.

The short answer is 'No, you can't do that'.

### The long answer

The reason this works in VSC is that Python has a system variable called `PYTHONPATH`.  Python searches all of the directories in `PYTHONPATH` to find the file. VSC knows this and adds the directory containing your module to `PYTHONPATH`.

For various reasons, Blender *ignores* `PYTHONPATH` by default. So it can't find modules that VSC can.

### The workaround

You can work around this by

- running Blender with the command line argument [`--python-use-system-env`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) and
- Adding the parent directory of your module to the search path using code along the lines of

```
import sys
sys.path.append("PATH_TO_YOUR_MODULE")
```

before you try to import it.  That's only the path to the directory containing the module. Don't include the module name.

### Background

You may want to read the Python manual section on the import system; especially the paragraph about [*searching*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching).  The key bit has to do with *import path*

> A list of locations (or path entries) that are searched by the path based finder for modules to import. During import, this list of locations usually comes from sys.path, but for subpackages it may also come from the parent package’s **path** attribute.

For a discussion of Blender and `PYTHONPATH`, see [this answer](https://attempted%20relative%20import%20with%20no%20known%20parent%20package)

Comment: Then what are the other custom addons? They still use normal `import syntax` for fetching their own sub-modules especially like this one; https://github.com/curtisjamesholt/BY-GEN-public

Comment: Custom addons _are_ Python files.  That's why ordinary syntax works in them.  The console is not a Python file.

Comment: So you say I can't use the `import syntax` on built-in text editor of the Blender because it doesn't support? Sorry if I bother you I can't fully understand because I'm not a Native English speaker.

Comment: Don't worry, you're not bothering me.   I have not written a clear enough answer, so I will try to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for understanding me. Speaking of which, I found a related answer from a question which has the same problem with me. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817 I followed exactly same way such as changing files’ and folders' names, inserting `register-unregister` functions to every each `.py` files etc.. But sadly, it still throws the `attempted relative` error.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo You're welcome.  It will take me a little while to write a better answer, so please be patient.

Comment: Appreciated for detailed answer. Maybe I'll just write down an one `.py` file.